# Stack-Reference of a Heap-Object

Tags: pointers, memory-management, rust

After reading several articles about **The Heap and the Stack** (Rust-lang) I learned that non-primitive types / data-structures are usually located on the heap, leaving a pointer in the stack, pointing to the address where the specific object is located at the heap.

> Heap values are referenced by a variable on the stack, which contains the memory address of the object on the heap. *[Rust Essentials, Ivo Balbaert]*

Considering the following example:

```
struct Point {
    x: u32,
    y: u32,
}

fn main() {
    let point = Point { x: 8, y: 16 };

    // Is this address the value of the pointer at the stack, which points to
    // the point-struct allocated in the heap, or is the printed address the 
    // heap-object's one?
    println!("The struct is located at the address {:p}", &point);
}
```

In my case, the output was:

> The struct is located at the address 0x24fc58

So, is **0x24fc58** the value (address) the stack-reference points to, or is it the direct memory-address where the struct-instance is allocated in the heap?

Some additional little questions:

- Is this a "raw-address", or the address relative to the program's address-space?
- Is it possible to initialize a pointer by directly passing a hex address?
- Is it possible to access memory-addresses which don't lay in the program's address-space?

Comment: *"usually non-primitive types/Data-structures are located at the heap"* -- Where did you read this? The excerpt you quoted doesn't say or imply it. There are some languages where this is the case (like Java), but with Rust, the type of an object does not determine where that object is located. You can choose to create an object of any type on either the stack or the heap.

Comment: >>_Primitive values such as numbers (like 32 in the fiure),
characters, and true/false values are stored on the stack, while the value of more
complex objects that could grow in size are stored in the heap Memory_<< Rust Essentials (book).

Comment: I don't have that book, but did a search on that text, and was able to view a portion of it. He doesn't expound upon it too much, but I would guess (since he refers to complex objects that could grow in size), he is referring to dynamically allocating structures like `String` and `Vec`. But even in that case, the objects themselves can be created on the stack, but internally, they hold pointers to values on the heap. But those values weren't put on the heap because of what type they are. They were put there explicitly by the implementation functions of `String` and `Vec`.

Comment: Thank you very much for making such an effort!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Point` actually resides on the stack – there is no `Box` or other structure to put it on the heap.

Yes, it is possible (though obviously unsafe) to pass an address to a `*ptr` (this is a bare pointer) and cast it to a `&ptr` – this is unsafe, because the latter are guaranteed to be non-null.

As such, it is of course *possible* (though wildly unsafe) to access off-heap memory, as long as the underlying system lets you do it (most current systems will probably just kill your process with a Segmentation Fault).